# Differential of a stochastic process $I(t) = e^{\sigma W(t)}$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

I need to compute the differential $dI$ of $I(t) = e^{\sigma W(t)}$ where $W(t)$ is a brownian motion.

With $I(W_t) = e^{\sigma W_t}$ I can apply Itô's lemma and get $dI =\frac{\partial I}{\partial W_t}dW_t +\frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2I}{\partial W^2_t}dt=\sigma e^{\sigma W_t}dW_t+\frac{1}{2}\sigma ^2e^{\sigma W_t}dt$.

With $I(t)$ how can I get $dI$?

Answer (score 1):

This is just an application of Ito's calculus.

Let $dX_t=\tilde \mu(X_t)dt+\tilde\sigma(X_t)dW_t$ for some approprtiate functions $\tilde\mu,\tilde\sigma$. From Ito's formula we get that for some $C^2$ function $f$ we have that

$$df(X_t) = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}dX_t+\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}\tilde{\sigma}(X_t)^2dt.$$

Now let $f(X_t)=\exp(\sigma X_t)$ with $X_t=W_t$, then we have that
$dX_t=dW_t$, and hence $\tilde\mu(\cdot)=0$ and $\tilde\sigma(\cdot)=1$. Therefore,

$$df(X_t) = \sigma \exp(\sigma X_t)dW_t+\dfrac{\sigma ^2}{2}\exp(\sigma X_t)dt.$$

If we let $I_t=f(X_t)$, we then obtain

$$dI_t = \frac{1}{2}\sigma ^2I_tdt + \sigma I_tdW_t,\ I_0=1$$

which is the equation of a geometric Brownian motion. You can verify that the formula is correct using the explicit formula for the solution of the geometric Brownian motion.

Comment: Thank you. I can't seem to understand how to get the differential of $I(t)$ because the argument of $I$ is $t$ and not $W_t$. What am I missing?

Comment: The notation $\frac{\partial I}{\partial W}$ is a bit misleading, as you are not taking the derivative with respect to Brownian motion, but rather the space variable in $I$.

Comment: @JoseAvilez Yes, that was hastily written with some bad copy-paste. I have now improved the answer.